# performance hit with strongname public key (snk)?

Tags: .net, performance

Is a dll **with** a strongname public key (**snk**) significantly **slower** than without ?

Comment: if anyone is wondering: the slow performance was on offline servers. solved through  <runtime><generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false" /></runtime>  in the app.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope there won't be any difference during the code execution, which would be your primary concern anyway. There will be minimal overhead during the time that the assembly is being loaded, as the strong naming will be verified, but that's minimal since hashing is a blazingly fast operation.

Comment: Do you know if the verifying process at loading time will (or can) check the publisher (over the net) ?

Comment: Published info is stored in the installer manifest (for ClickOnce) and the manifest can also be signed with a code-signing certificate, which definitely verifies the publisher.